# How to create a histogram horizontal? [algorithm] JAVA

Tags: java

I was doing this exercise but i cant solved the algorithm, can you guys please help me with it?

This is my code if someone can solved this for me, ill appreciate so much i dont know how long i was trying to do it, i did on vertical but cant solved on horizontal. Hope someone can solved it.

Thanks

```
    // 10. A histogram is a graph that shows how often a given list of histograms appears.
    // different values that could form it. Make a histogram with values between
    // For example, if the list consists of: 6, 4, 4, 1, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 4, su
    // histogram would be:
    //                 *
    //                 *   *
    //                 * * *     *
    //           * * * * * * *   *
    //         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    // This indicates that 0 and 8 do not appear at all, that 1, 2, 3 and 7 appear once, 5 and 9 appear twice.
    // times, etc. Write an algorithm that reads a list of numbers between 0 and 9 (the list
    // will end when a negative number is read) and print a histogram like the previous one on the screen.

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int num;

    System.out.println("Cantidad de elementos: ");
    num = leerInt(); // Almacenamos cantidad de elementos

    int valor[] = new int[num]; // Creamos el vector

    for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Que numero quieres meter en array %d: %n",i);
        num = leerInt();
        valor[i] = num;
    }

    histograma(valor); // Mostramos el histograma

}


public static void histograma(int[] v) { // Hace el histograma
    int count=0, count2=0, num=0;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<v.length; j++) {
            //System.out.printf("  ");
            if(v[j]==i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>count2) {
            count2=count;
            num=i;
        }
        count=0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<v.length; j++) {
            if (v[j]==i) {
                count++;
            }
            if (j==num&&count<count2) {
                System.out.printf("* ");
            }else {
                System.out.printf("  ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ",i);
    }
}

}
```

Result by console:

```
Cantidad de elementos: 
3
Que numero quieres meter en array 0: 
2
Que numero quieres meter en array 1: 
1
Que numero quieres meter en array 2: 
2
    * 
    * 








0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my teacher and this is my solution:

```
import static proyectoTeclado.Teclado.*;

public class Ejercicio10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num=1,max=0;
        int valor[]=new int[10];
        boolean stop=false;

        while(!stop) {
            System.out.println("Introduce numero: ");
            num=leerInt();
            if(num>=0&&num<=9) {
                valor[num]++;
                if(valor[num]>max) {
                    max=valor[num];
                }
            }else if(num>9) {
                System.out.println("Introduce solo entre 0 o 9, si quieres parar pon un numero negativo.");
            }else {
                stop=true;
            }
        }

        histograma(valor,max);

    }


    public static void histograma(int[] v, int max) { // Hace el histograma

        for(int i=max; i>0; i--) {
            for(int j=0; j<v.length; j++) {
                if(v[j]>=i) {
                    System.out.print("* ");

                }else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ",i);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just count the numbers and print them in their space. As you can see the **number of rows is max count** and the **number of columns is 9**
[Note : The loop has to run for the max count]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the total size : ");
      int n= scanner.nextInt();
      int [] values = new int[n];
      int [] count = new int[9];
      int max = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter "+ n +" numbers between 1 to 9 :");
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
          values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
          ++count[values[i]];
          if(count[values[i]] >max)
              max=count[values[i]];
      }
      histogram(max, count);

   }

   static void histogram(int max, int[] count) {
      for(int i=max;i>0;i--) {
          for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
              if(count[j]>=i) {
                  System.out.print("* ");
              }else {
                  System.out.print("  ");
              }
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
      for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
          System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
 }
```

Output :

[image]